# CSS resize of Fixed quantity

Tags: html, css

Hello I have problems with DIV re-size.

I have no idea why but all my div of a specific class in a specific section are 70px bigger than what they are suppost to be. This happend either if the div of this class is 300px or it is 800px.

For this reason I can not use any percentage since there is no fixed value. The height depends only on how much text is in the div.

How can I remore this offset? I can use anything even Javascript or similar.

I already did something like:

margin-bottom: -70px;

It works, but with this solution the div of the previuse article overlap the new title.Making part of the title un-clickable.

Thanks

Edit:

My current CSS for this section is empty.

Sure thanks..

```
<div class="lcp_catlist">
<div class="list_cat_begin_post">

        <a href="..."><img ..."></a>

        <span class="list_cat_post_title_span"> 
            <span class="list_cat_post_data"> 4 gennaio 2015</span>
            <a href="....">TITLE</a>
        </span>

        <div class="list_cat_excerpt">
            EXCERPT
        </div>
   </div>
..... [many <div class="list_cat_begin_post">]

</div>

.lcp_catlist {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
}

.list_cat_begin_post {
}

.list_cat_post_title_span {
position: relative;
top: -95px;`enter code here`
background: rgba(12, 97, 157, 0.7);
color: white;
display: table-cell;
width: 620px;
height: 75px;
```

}

```
.list_cat_excerpt {
position: relative;
top: -80px;
bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: solid;
border-color: rgb(12, 97, 157);
```

}

Snapshot with the problem![The red square hilight the space that should not be present] 
 http://i62.tinypic.com/zxn24n.png

Comment: Yes, include the CSS and HTML (as simplest as possible) please, and specify which height you suppose these DIVs should have.

Comment: they can have different size since the size of the div depends on the content is in there. So I cannot specify a fixed height. I can only say that all of them should be 70px smaller.

Comment: I understood where the problem come from. It is due to "list_cat_post_title_span". I add this span to add a background behind the title. However, even if I overlap this div to the image the browser add its size to the main div. Increasing its size. Is there any way to avid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

after seeing the code that's been added I would say that it's the position relatives that is causing the problem. when you set something to position relative its place in the document is kept as if it was there, it is then moved to it position RELATIVE to where it would normally be at the same timebut preserving it's space where it would be. so the snippet to see what I mean, it has pushed the green box down but is still keeping it's place in the document.

```css
#box2{width:150px;height:30px;background-color:yellow;}
#box3{width:150px;height:30px;background-color:blue;}
#box4{position:relative;width:150px;height:30px;top:10px;background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div id="box2">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="box4">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="box3">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set each div of your specific class to what you want it to be then. If you post your code, I could perhaps tell you exactly what is wrong because your question is a little hard to decipher.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing the list_cat_post_title_span class, I suspect on several styles:

- Mainly, why `display: table-cell`? The table-cell layout is intended to make several adjacent elements appear as if the were cells: same widht and/or height. But, if you are setting specific width and height in that same class, it does not seem coherent. Better remove the `display` style.
- I also do not understand the `top: -95px` and the `position: relative` styles. I recommend you to turn them off and try if the extra-height problem still shows.